# How can I split the results to show only 10

Tags: php, mysql

I'm building a review system as a php script, I want to make the pagination, as well the pagination is workin but I have a problem.
The full results come from db as array, and I need to use LIMIT $VAR, $VAR2,
For full code please rfer to github.com/EasycryptosTeam/review-system

```php
    $query = "
    SELECT * FROM avatrade 
    ORDER BY review_id DESC LIMIT 1, 5
    ";

    $result = $pdo->query($query, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    foreach($result as $row)
    {
        $review_content[] = array(
            'user_name'     =>  $row["user_name"],
            'user_review'   =>  $row["user_review"],
            'rating'        =>  $row["user_rating"],
            'user_avatar'   => $row["user_avatar"],
            'datetime'      =>  date('l jS, F Y h:i:s A', $row["datetime"])
        );

        if($row["user_rating"] == '5')
        {
            $five_star_review++;
        }

        if($row["user_rating"] == '4')
        {
            $four_star_review++;
        }

        if($row["user_rating"] == '3')
        {
            $three_star_review++;
        }

        if($row["user_rating"] == '2')
        {
            $two_star_review++;
        }

        if($row["user_rating"] == '1')
        {
            $one_star_review++;
        }

        $total_review++;

        $total_user_rating = $total_user_rating + $row["user_rating"];

    }
   
   if ($total_user_rating == 0 && $total_review == 0)
   {
        $average_rating= '0';
        
       }else{
            $average_rating = $total_user_rating / $total_review;
            
        }

   
    $output = array(
        'average_rating'    =>  number_format($average_rating, 1),
        'total_review'      =>  $total_review,
        'five_star_review'  =>  $five_star_review,
        'four_star_review'  =>  $four_star_review,
        'three_star_review' =>  $three_star_review,
        'two_star_review'   =>  $two_star_review,
        'one_star_review'   =>  $one_star_review,
        'review_data'       =>  $review_content,
        
    
    );

    echo json_encode($output);
```

As you can see, Im getting 5 results and it´s OK, but the total rating is also shown as 5.

I would like to split the query on two part to have control over

Answer (score -1):

I hope I helped you!

This is part of my code to get this result

[image]

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM review_table WHERE product_id='1' ORDER BY review_id DESC";
$result = $connect->query($query, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
    foreach($result as $row)
    {
       $review_content[] = array(
'user_name' =>  $row["user_name"],
'user_review'   =>  $row["user_review"],
'rating'        =>  $row["user_rating"],
'datetime'      =>  date('l jS, F Y h:i:s A', $row["datetime"])
        );
        if($row["user_rating"] == '5')
        {
            $five_star_review++;
        }
        if($row["user_rating"] == '4')
        {
            $four_star_review++;
        }
        if($row["user_rating"] == '3')
        {
            $three_star_review++;
        }
        if($row["user_rating"] == '2')
        {
            $two_star_review++;
        }
        if($row["user_rating"] == '1')
        {
            $one_star_review++;
        }
        $total_review++;
$total_user_rating = $total_user_rating + $row["user_rating"]; 
    }
    $average_rating = $total_user_rating  / 
       $total_review;
       $output = array(
'average_rating'    =>  number_format($average_rating, 1),
'total_review'      =>  $total_review,
'five_star_review'  =>  $five_star_review,
'four_star_review'  =>  $four_star_review,
'three_star_review' =>  $three_star_review,
'two_star_review'   =>  $two_star_review,
'one_star_review'   =>  $one_star_review,
'review_data'       =>  $review_content
    );
    echo json_encode($output);
```

Comment: Please explain how your answer helps solve the original problem. Comments in your code would help as well.

Comment: why don't you ask the database to count all stars in one query?